# Best way to handle Path Manipulation vulnerabilities with retrieving files from .appconfig?

Tags: .net, fortify

I'm currently working on a task where I am trying to suppress some Path Manipulation warnings that have been raised from running an analysis with Fortify on my team's source code. The issues are being raised due to the fact that we are trying to read/write from some files given in a user's specified directory. Here is an example below:

```
string pathWithFile = AppConfigHelper.ReadAppConfigString("UsersPath");

if (Directory.Exists(pathWithFile))
{
    // do stuff with file from path
}
```

Now I understand after reading the warning details/suggestions and doing research why this is a security issue, but my question is how should this best be resolved? As it stands, my team is building this application with the assumption that the information that is to be retrieved is supplied through a third-party vendor to our customer, so we have no way of knowing where the user may place this file in their system.

We also have to worry about creating files with our information within this same directory, but I'd imagine whichever solution (if any) that can be applied to the former scenario can be applied there as well.